# stdev and mean from gaussian fit vs. from classical formula

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I have a set of data - measured speed of molecules in water.
I made a histogram and fitted it with function
$$A\exp\frac{(x-B)^2}{C}$$
calculating mean and standard deviation from values B and C

If I use the classical formula for standard deviation the results are different.
It's clear they can't be the same. I guess the problem is, that I don't have enough data.

But now what is the difference between those values? Which one is better to use?

[image: Dashed is gaussian with classically computed stdev and mean, full it the fitted gaussian]

Comment: At least one of your curves has the wrong area beneath it (at least integrated across all the reals)

Comment: Well they are not normed. For the dashed function I used A instead of the normal coeficient so that the curves are easier to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitting a curve to a histogram is troublesome, because the result will in general depend on the number and width of the *bins* you chose when creating the histogram.

For an extreme example, assume you measured the values $\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\}$. If your bins are $\left((-1,0],(0,1],(1,2]\right)$, your histogram is $\left(0,4,0\right)$. If, on the other hand, your bins are $\left((-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}],(\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4}],(\frac{5}{4},\frac{9}{4}]\right)$, the hisogram becomes $\left(2,2,0\right)$. The two histograms will lead to different results when you fit the normal distribution's density to them - in particular, the resulting distribution's variance will be higher for the second histogram than it will be for the first.

So unless you have a very good reason to determine the distribution's parameters by fitting the density to the histogram, using some other estimator is usually better. For the normal distribution, using the sample average to estimate the distribution's mean, and the sample variance to estimate the distribution's variance is a maximum-likelyhood estimator, and probably a good choice.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the dependence on number of bins is a very good point. what if I wanted to determine how well the distribution represents normal distribution? would this be suitable than?
it's for physics lab report and one of the tasks was actually to fit the histogram, so i'm trying to find out what could be the reason
i'll probably mention this fact in the discussion section

Comment: @Tom83B A statistically sound way to test if data is distributed according to some known distribution is the one-sided [Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Comment: @Tom83B Though if you determine the distribution's parameter from the same dataset that you use to do the test, as you seem to require, the test doesn't really work (though it might still be approximately correct, I dunno). The problem is that the test statistic the K-S-Test uses comes out too small in this case, because you moved the distributed closer to the actual data by estimating it's parameters. For the special case of the normal distribution, you can use the [Lilliefor-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test), which accounts for that.